# Values inserted in simulator but not showing in database table

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, sqlite

I have created an `insert` statement for my SQLite database that inserts records. My code works properly -- when I run my code, it shows a message that a new record was added.

When I open SQLite Browser to see if the record was added to the database table, the record does not appear. What could be the problem? My code is working properly. It shows the contact added message in the simulator, but in the database the contact is not added.

This is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TAddNewJourney.h"

@interface insertAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    TAddNewJourney *iC;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TAddNewJourney *iC;

-(void) chekAndCreateDatabase;
-(void)insert;
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "insertAppDelegate.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "TAddNewJourney.h"

#import "Global.h"

@implementation insertAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize iC;

static NSString* databaseName;
static NSString* databasePath;
static sqlite3* database;





  -(void) chekAndCreateDatabase
{
    BOOL success;
    databaseName=@"demo.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDir, databaseName];
    NSLog(@"Database Path is: %@", databasePath);
    NSLog(@"Database Name is: %@", databaseName);

    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == NO ) {
        // Open database.
        if( sqlite3_open( [databasePath UTF8String], &database ) == SQLITE_OK ) {
            char* errorMsg;
            // Create Articles Table.
            const char* articlesTable = "CREATE TABLE [UserJourney] (name text, location text)";
            if( sqlite3_exec(database, articlesTable, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK )
                NSLog( @"Fail to create UserJourney table. Error is: %@", errorMsg );


        } else NSLog(@"Fail to Create/Open database");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Open database.");
        sqlite3_open( [databasePath UTF8String], &database );
    }
}



-(void)insert{
    [self chekAndCreateDatabase];

// Create Pre Sqlite query string.
NSString* preSqliteQuery = @"INSERT INTO UserJourney  VALUES ('%@', '%@')";

// Create Sqlite query string.
NSString* queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:preSqliteQuery,Gjourney,Glocation];
// Execute query.
if(sqlite3_exec(database, [queryString UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL)== SQLITE_DONE){

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Record added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    alert = nil;
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"not Added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release]; 
    alert = nil;
}
```

This is my controller class:

```
@interface TAddNewJourney : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextField *mTextJourney;
    IBOutlet UITextField *mTextLocation;
        IBOutlet UIButton *mStart;
    IBOutlet UIButton *mCancel;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain)UITextField *textjourney;
@property (nonatomic,retain)UITextField *textlocation;

-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)Cancel:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "TAddNewJourney.h"
#import "Global.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "insertAppDelegate.h"


@implementation TAddNewJourney
@synthesize textjourney=mTextJourney;
@synthesize textlocation =mTextLocation;

-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{
    Gjourney = mTextJourney.text;
    Glocation = mTextLocation.text;

       insertAppDelegate *app=(insertAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [app insert];

}
```

Comment: put some code so any one can try to give you some suggestion

Comment: have you copied the database to your documents directory.. and are you checking that copy for data after insertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in this way

```
   NSString* str = [NSString stringwithformat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO insert (textfieldm, textfieldn) VALUES ('%@', '%@')", Gunameq, Gpassq];
    if(sqlite3_exec(database, [str UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Record added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        alert = nil;
}
else {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"not Added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release]; 
        alert = nil;
}
```

I think in this way you can do it !!! Good luck !!!

Comment: what you mean by "I dont have to use.. "?

Comment: and why you have use that function? because to insert data in database you dont need to use that function. "sqlite3_prepare_v2_statement" used to create compiled statements to fetch data from database using select query.. getting ??

Comment: also "sqlite3_step" used to fetch data row by row from compiled statement, it will not execute your query..

Comment: Why you want to use sqlite3_prepare_v2_statement ??? You can do in this way too without sqlite3_prepare_v2_statement !! I think !!

Comment: [link](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) here you can read and find answer on your question !!!

Comment: In your given example you only create database and want to add there columns .... I think at first you must create columns then insert in to database !!!

Answer (score 0):

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface SqliteDatabase : NSObject {


}

// Check and Create Sqlite Table.
+ (void) CheckAndCreateDatabase;
+ (void) insert;

@end
```

.m file

```
// Static Variables.
static NSString* dataBaseName;
static NSString* dataBasePath;
static sqlite3*  database;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Check and Create Sqlite Table.
+ (void) CheckAndCreateDatabase {
    NSLog(@"\nCall of: CheckAndCreateDatabase");
    // Set database name.
    dataBaseName = @"Database.db";
    // Initialize database path.
    NSArray* paths         = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    dataBasePath           = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDir, dataBaseName];
    NSLog(@"Database Path is: %@", dataBasePath);
    NSLog(@"Database Name is: %@", dataBaseName);

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem.
    if( [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataBasePath] == NO ) {
        // Open database.
        if( sqlite3_open( [dataBasePath UTF8String], &database ) == SQLITE_OK ) {
            char* errorMsg;
            // Create Articles Table.
            const char* articlesTable = "CREATE TABLE [TableName] (textfieldm, text, textfieldn text)";
            if( sqlite3_exec(database, articlesTable, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK )
                NSLog( @"Fail to create [TableName] table. Error is: %@", errorMsg );


        } else NSLog(@"Fail to Create/Open database");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Open database.");
        sqlite3_open( [dataBasePath UTF8String], &database );
    }
}
```

Here is how you must insert

```
+ (void) insert {
    // Create Pre Sqlite query string.
    NSString* preSqliteQuery = @"INSERT INTO [TableName] (textfieldm, textfieldn VALUES ('%@', '%@')";

    // Create Sqlite query string.
    NSString* queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:preSqliteQuery, Gunameq, Gpassq];
    // Execute query.
    sqlite3_exec(database, [queryString UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

If I help you don't forget to rate me !!! Good Luck !!!

Comment: Do you have sqlite manager if not install it and check your database with it !!! If you write code as I gave in example it must work properly !!!

Comment: Can you send me file witch you want to create in order me to see and correct it !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite3_exec(database, [queryString UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
NSLog("Error is: %@");
```

Add NSLog line and see logs after that tell me please what error occurs in your project. Maybe in that way I can tell you what to do.

Comment: i get this error:Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
kill
quit

Comment: from this line( sqlite3_exec(database, articlesTable, NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK )

Comment: Do not call  [self chekAndCreateDatabase]; from insert because every time you press button new table will be creaed !!!